# How do i close react js application programatically

Tags: reactjs, android-webview

I am launching **reactjs** webpage from andorid webview .
This page has **backbutton**.
I want to know is there a way i can close the webviewactivity on click of that backbutton.

Actually i want 'onCloseWindow' of webChromeClient to be called

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSBridge to call a method in your webviewactivity when you click the back button. In this method, call `this.finish()`  to finish the webviewactivity.

Comment: Actually i want 'onCloseWindow' of webChromeClient to be called. Not by adding jsbridge

Comment: `onCloseWindow ` would not be called. It is used to notify the host application to close the given WebView and remove it from the view system if necessary.(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCloseWindow(android.webkit.WebView)